# Jasmine spy object dependent on another object, inject mock

Tags: typescript, jasmine

I have the following TypeScript constructor in a Security.ts class

```
constructor(readonly idOptions: IdentityOptions) {
    console.log('constructor called');
    this.lock = new Auth0Lock(idOptions.clientId, idOptions.domain, {
        auth: {
            redirectUrl: idOptions.redirectUrl,
            responseType: 'code',
            params: {
                scope: 'openid'
            }
        },
        initialScreen: idOptions.initialScreen,
        allowedConnections: ['Username-Password-Authentication']
    });
}
```

Now in the unit tests for Security.ts (using Jasmine) I want to mock the Auth0Lock object completely instead of calling the real Auth0Lock object.  How can I do this using Jasmine spies?

Answer (score 0):

After creating instance of your security class you can assign your Auth0Lock mock object to instance `lock` property. Something like this:

```
let securityObject = new SecurityClass();
let mockedAuth0Lock = {
    clientId1: 22,
    someMethod: jasmine.createSpy('Auth0LockMethod')
};
securityObject.lock = mockedAuth0Lock;
```